# rendering frame with image save every .... ( 100?) samples

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, scripting, performance

For a project I'm working on I want to do some test renders to see how many samples I would need for the final image. I want to do this as time efficient as possible so I was wondering if there is any possibility I could set the samples really high, use progressive refine and let the image auto-save every, let's say, 100 samples ( or whatever number you put in maybe ). if someone knows a way of doing this albeit with a script, please let me know

Answer (score 5):

You can render an animation with 100 (same) frames after clicking the variable seed button (clock icon), and setting samples to 100.

[image: variable seed]

Averaging image1 with image2 would be equivalent to the image with 200 samples, averaging images 1, 2 and 3 would be equivalent to the image with 300 samples and so on.

Photoshop or gimp could help you with that but you could do it more quickly with imagemagick

```
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg ... N.jpg -average result.jpg
```

Here is the code in bash that echoes the commands to run

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do
    echo -n "convert "
    for j in `seq -f "%03g" 1 $i`;
        do
                echo -n "$j.png "
        done    
    echo "-average result.jpg"
done
```

and here are the commands for 10 images in case you are on windows

```
convert 001.png 002.png -average result.jpg
convert 001.png 002.png 003.png -average result.jpg
convert 001.png 002.png 003.png 004.png -average result.jpg
convert 001.png 002.png 003.png 004.png 005.png -average result.jpg
convert 001.png 002.png 003.png 004.png 005.png 006.png -average result.jpg
convert 001.png 002.png 003.png 004.png 005.png 006.png 007.png -average result.jpg
convert 001.png 002.png 003.png 004.png 005.png 006.png 007.png 008.png -average result.jpg
convert 001.png 002.png 003.png 004.png 005.png 006.png 007.png 008.png 009.png -average result.jpg
convert 001.png 002.png 003.png 004.png 005.png 006.png 007.png 008.png 009.png 010.png -average result.jpg
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and I tried something similar already but for this particular project the image is different with this method. The scene has a small planet with a volumetric atmosphere and with combining seeds the volume is way less thick and noticable

Comment: I really wonder why I wrote a whole program to list all the files instead of `convert *.png -average out.png`